# How to change a row of cells on excel 2010 depending on different cell data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Can anyone help me with a problem I'm having on excel 2010 please?

I am trying to change the colour of part of a row of cells when certain data is input.  For example I want cells A13 to G13 to change to yellow when all cells in between are not blank and G13 is YES.  If all cells in between were populated and G13 is NO I want the cells to turn orange.

Also I am trying to get cells A13 to H13 to turn green if H13 is populated by any name from the drop down list applied to that the H13 cell.

Any help is gratefully received.

Neil

Answer (score 0):

You want to use conditional formatting.

Two helpful notes that not everyone realizes:

- At the bottom of the dropdown is the option to set conditional formatting according to formulas. When you use the Formula Is option, you can enter any formula that results in the logical values TRUE (1) or FALSE (0). For example, you could use a logical formula such as the following: `=N4>AVERAGE($N$4:$N$37)` (*[Microsoft tutorial - Creating conditional formatting formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/creating-conditional-formatting-formulas-HA001111661.aspx)*)
- You can apply multiple conditions to a cell or set of cells and then order the conditions so that condition A is checked before condition C and so on.